# onclick is not working for dynamically added buttons

Tags: jquery

I have one div section with dynamic data and static button.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="subSection">                    
    <section>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger hideEquipmentDetails" onclick="clickme()"><i class="fa fa-times" ></i></button>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
details()
    function details(){
    var details= response.data.filters;
        $.each(details,function(i,value){
        $('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+value.speed+'</label></section>');
    });
    }

function clickme(){
$('.main').hide();
}
</script>
```

Here click me function works fine when button is clicked.

Am refreshing the method for every 5 seconds.so I need to clear the previous html content of `.subSection` when method is loaded.So I have decided to append a button dynamically.

I changed my code like this:

```
HTML:

    <div class="main">
        <div class="subSection">                    
        </div>
    </div>

SCRIPT:

    <script>
    details()
        function details(){
        $('subSection').html('');
        var details= response.data.filters;
            $.each(details,function(i,value){
            $('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+value.speed+'</label></section>');
        });
     $('.subSection').append('<section><button type="button"  class="btn 
   btn-danger hideEquipmentDetails" onclick="clickme()"><i class="fa fa-
   times" ></i></button>
        </section>')
        }

    function clickme(){
    $('.main').hide();
    }
    </script>
```

But `clickme` method is not triggered now.I tried using `.click` also.Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: You might be better off using `$(document).on('click', '.hideEquipmentDetails', function() { $('.main').hide() });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone by giving great ideas and I got solution for by question by just making an simple change in my code.

```
 function details(){
        $('subSection').html('');
        $('.subSection').append('<section><button type="button"  class="btn  btn-danger hideEquipmentDetails" onclick="clickme()"><i class="fa fa-
   times" ></i></button>
        </section>')
        var details= response.data.filters;
            $.each(details,function(i,value){
            $('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+value.speed+'</label></section>');
        });
        }
```

Just append the button first then append the data.

Answer (score 2):

`.on()` works on dynamically created elements if used with the following syntax:

`$(document).on('click', '<selector>', function() {});`

```
$(document).on('click', '.hideEquipmentDetails', function() { 
  $('.main').hide();
});
```

Comment: @Barskey as you said `on()` works on dynamically created elements, this is not always true, but the thing is that `on()` always works on dynamically created elements only if it is use like below.
`$(parent).on('click', '.dynamic_element', function() { 
  // do somthing here
});`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with below, @AbdullahShoaib

Comment: @Barskey check again.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib What exactly are you trying to clarify?

Comment: @Barskey i just want to clarify that your statement " `.on()` works on dynamically created elements " is not always valid. Make sense ?

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib Could you represent a situation in what `.on()` doesn't work?

Comment: $('.dynamic_element').on('click',function(){ // this code will not work });

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `onclick` attribute is not used when adding html dynamically.

Changing your code to this should work:

```
$('.subSection').append('<section><button type="button" class="btn '+
  'btn-danger hideEquipmentDetails"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>'+
  '</button></section>').find('button').click(clickme)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the particular function declaration inside the `<body>` tag and it will work automatically for dynamically created buttons.

```
<script>
  function clickme(){
  alert("test");
  $('.main').hide();
 }
</script>
<div class="main">
   <div class="subSection">                    
   </div>
</div>
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
details();

        function details(){
        $('subSection').html('');
        /*var details= response.data.filters;
            $.each(details,function(i,value){
            $('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+value.speed+'</label></section>');
        });*/
     $('.subSection').append('<section><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hideEquipmentDetails" onClick="clickme()"><i class="fa fa-times" ></i>TEST</button></section>');
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function clickme(){
      alert("test");
      $('.main').hide();
     }
    </script>
   <div class="main">
       <h1>Test Content</h1>
        <div class="subSection">                    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which comment??

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#add_button").click(function(){
    count+=1;
    $(".container").append('<button>Button '+count+'</button>');
  })

  $(".container").on('click', 'button', function(){
    alert("Button " + $(this).html() + " clicked");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.container{padding:10px}
.container button{padding:3px; margin:5px; border: solid 1px red;}
</style>

<button id="add_button">Add</button>

<div class="container">
</div>
```